# Настройка nginx на 3 сайта

Tags: nginx, lemp

Ранее на сервере работал один сайт на *prestashop*. Сейчас понадобилось, чтобы работало еще пару сайтов. Нашел [генератор](https://nginxconfig.io/). Сейчас работает только 1 сайт. Один сайт почему то переадресовывает на первый домен.
и этот первый домен просто не работает — логи чисты. Может что то не так с конфигурацией? Буду благодарен за любую подсказку. в **Nginx** не очень разбираюсь.

> **Ubuntu 18.04**
> **php 7.2**

[Генератор конфинга nginx](https://nginxconfig.io/?0.domain=upmelevel.ru&0.path=%2Fvar%2Fwww%2Fupmelevel&0.document_root=%2F&0.non_www=false&0.redirect=false&0.https=false&0.cert_type=custom&0.magento&0.access_log_domain&0.error_log_domain&1.domain=gearhub.ru&1.document_root=%2F&1.non_www=false&1.redirect=false&1.cert_type=custom&1.ssl_certificate=%2Fetc%2Fssl%2Fcerts%2Fgearhub.crt&1.ssl_certificate_key=%2Fetc%2Fssl%2Fprivate%2Fgearhub.key&1.php_legacy_routing&1.access_log_domain&1.error_log_domain&2.domain=kenan-opt.ru&2.https=false&2.index=index.html&2.fallback_html&2.fallback_php=false&2.access_log_domain&2.error_log_domain&access_log=%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Faccess_upme.log&error_log=%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Ferror_upme.log%20warn&log_not_found)

upd.

sites-available

[image: sites-available]

sites-enabled

[image: sites-enabled]

Comment: Какой сайт? Какой первый сайт? Конфигурацию лучше описать здесь. Вы создали дополнительные файлы конфигурации и симлинки на них?

Comment: gearhub.ru - первый сайт, доп файлы, симлинки создал.. upmelevel перекидывает на www.gearhub.ru..

Comment: Покажите структуру папок `/sites-enabled` и `/sites-available`. В `upmelevel.ru.conf` уберите у домена `www.`

Comment: добавил в общий пост